# How get access to SAP sandbox via R?

Tags: r, hana, rodbc

I made registration on SAP ID Service to check how their sandbox works.

How it's possible to connect to the sandbox data tables by using R?

The examples I found:

```
library ("RODBC")
# 1
ch <- odbcConnect("data source name", uid = "test_hana" , pwd = "test12")
sqlQuery(ch, "SELECT * FROM '_SYS_BIC'.'BILLING_DATA'")

# 2
ch <- odbcConnect("HANA_TK", uid="xxxx", pwd="xxxx")
odbcQuery(ch, "SELECT table_name from SYS.CS_TABLES_ where schema_name = 'SFLIGHT'")
tables <- sqlGetResults(ch)

odbcClose(ch)
```

Both not work. And, it's unclear how to have access to at least one SAP table in the sandbox.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: If you can get a connection to the HANA DB (which is very trick when the cloud conector is involved) you should use the "set shema" statement first and then querry HANA within the shema without stateting it anymore: https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.03/en-US/20fd550375191014b886a338afb4cd5f.html

Comment: Do you have an access to database that sandbox is running on?

Comment: As the question does not contain any error message, the only "obvious" issue with the code is that the object names in the SQL statements are in *single* quotes, but should be in *double* quotes. Like so: `sqlQuery(ch, 'SELECT * FROM "_SYS_BIC"."BILLING_DATA"')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup ODBC connection into HANA in system settings, [here is how](https://mccoy-partners.com/updates/sap-hana-and-r-how-to-integrate-the-outside-in-approach) or [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/23/r-integration-with-sap-hana/), and then you must install and load RODBC package in R:

```
> install.packages("RODBC")
> library("RODBC")
```

Then connect to HANA through the connection string:

```
> channel <- odbcConnect(“data source name”,uid=”test_hana”,pwd=”test12″);
```

and pull data like this:

```
> sqlQuery(channel, ‘SELECT * FROM “_SYS_BIC”.”BILLING_DATA” ‘)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is the same I mentioned in the question.

Comment: What exact error do you get? "Not work" says nothing, SAP ID is delegation authority service for web-based authentication, SAML etc, it is irrelevant here. Since June 4 2018 you can access Cloud HANA [directly via ODBC](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cc53ad464a57404b8d453bbadbc81ceb/Cloud/en-US/5bd9bcec690346a8b36df9161b1343c2.html). Describe your configuration in details, what kind of creds do you feed to RODBC